# Jquery IF Statement Less Than issue

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

This should be simple but I seem to be missing something..

```
start = $('[name=start]').val().split('.');
last = start[3];
end = $('[name=end]').val();

if (end < last) {
   alert('BLAH BLAH');
   return false;
}
```

I've alerted the values out and for one test I could see

last = 100

end = 90

So `if ( 90 < 100 )` alert should be shown but isn't.

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Try converting them to int. `if ( parseInt(end) < parseInt(last) ) { ... }`

Comment: Did you check your browser console?

Comment: jQuery.val() returns string object, not number. So you compare strings instead numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values you are comparing are *strings*, not integers, so they are compared lexicographically. Try this in your browser console:

```
90 < 100       => true
"90" < "100"   => false
```

Convert them to numbers first to make a numeric comparison:

```
last = +start[3];   // The + prefix is equivalent to Number(start[3])
end = +$('[name=end]').val();
```

Note that the `+`/`Number(...)` approach will return `NaN` if either input is not a valid number; alternatively you could use `parseInt` which has somewhat different semantics.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was missing.
just started to check if they were numbers or not.. working great now !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`if (parseInt(end,10) < parseInt(last,10)) {
   alert('BLAH BLAH');
   return false;
}`

Comment: Much simpler (and faster) to just coerce the strings to numbers with something like the "+" suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
    if(parseInt(end) < parseInt(last)){

           //your code
    }
```

Comment: Much simpler (and faster) to just coerce the strings to numbers with something like the "+" suggested in another answer.